# Running a loop until x mod 10 =0

Tags: math-mode, loops

I need something like this LaTeX:

```
    while x mod 10 != 0:
       x++
```

My LaTeX translation which compiles infinitely is this:

```
    \newcommand{\lfn}{
    \loop \ifnum \pgfmathresult<1
     \stepcounter{x}
     \pgfmathparse{Mod(\arabic{x},2)==0?1:0}
    \repeat
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcounter{x}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{0}% initialize
\loop
\ifnum\pgfmathresult<1
  \stepcounter{x}%
  \pgfmathparse{Mod(\value{x},10)==0?1:0}
  \thex
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more general looping macro. In the template, `#1` stands for the current value in the loop. The optional argument is the modulo (default 10).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lfn}{ O{10} m +m }
 {% #1 (optional) is the modulo
  % #2 is the starting point
  % #3 is a template for what to do
  \cs_set:Nn \__noname_lfn_do:n { #3 }
  \noname_lfn:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__noname_lfn_index_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \noname_lfn:nn
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__noname_lfn_index_int { #2 }
  \int_do_until:nn
   { \int_mod:nn { \l__noname_lfn_index_int } { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \__noname_lfn_do:V \l__noname_lfn_index_int
    \int_incr:N \l__noname_lfn_index_int
   }
  \__noname_lfn_do:V \l__noname_lfn_index_int
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__noname_lfn_do:n {}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__noname_lfn_do:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb|\lfn{1}{The current value is #1\par}|

\lfn{1}{The current value is #1\par}

\bigskip

\verb|\lfn[6]{2}{The current value is #1\par}|

\lfn[6]{2}{The current value is #1\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the initialization thingy is already in my answer...

Comment: @marmot But not the templating. `;-)`

Comment: Yes, but I have the nicer avatar! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! One possibility is to use `pgffor` with `\breakforeach` for that. And your code also works provided one makes sure `\pgfmathparse` is initialized correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,10))}] in {1,...,15}
{\X
\ifnum\Y=0
\breakforeach
\fi
}

\newcounter{x}\setcounter{x}{0}

\newcommand{\lfn}{\pgfmathparse{0}
    \loop \ifnum \pgfmathresult<1
     \stepcounter{x}\thex,
     \pgfmathparse{Mod(\arabic{x},10)==0?1:0}
    \repeat
}
\lfn    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any packages for that, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zz[1]{%
#1,
\ifnum\numexpr10*\numexpr#1/10\relax\relax=#1\else
   \expandafter\zz\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}\fi}

\begin{document}

\zz{1}

\zz{35}

\end{document}
```